# Laravel routes aren't working with 1&1

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, web-hosting

Many many many topics about this, but I have to say that none are helping me a great deal.

I have a website with Laravel and Bootstrap uploaded to my root folder of 1&1. My root directory looks like this :

- app
- bootstrap
- logs
- public
- List item
- vendor
- artisan
- composer.json
- composer.lock
- CONTRIBUTING.mu
- readme.md
- composer.phar
- info.php
- server.php
- phpunit.xml

With the public directory being the way to access the views, I am pointing my browser to domain.co.uk/public, and that works absolutely fine!!! The home page loads, and there appears to be no problems.

I then click a link, and of course it goes pear shaped, I get the 1&1 "This domain has just been registered" which I assume is the 404. From doing some research, I can see that .htaccess in the /public directory could be the issue, but I haven't changed anything just in case.

I am sorry if this is a rather isolated incident, although I see lots of people having trouble with 1&1, the main issue being they have no live chat feature which is rediculous in this day and age.

Many thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: Do your links contain `/public/whatever`?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned. Yes, for example I have links to /account/number, which are indeed showing as /public/account/number. Many thanks.

Comment: Please share more details - why not put the DocRoot to the public folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few HOURS of searching, coding, and all that crap... I found it.

My basic package with 1&1 only allows me to use one directory, so instead of using `/public` I transferred everything from `/public` to `/`, then changed the paths in `/bootstrap/paths.php` and `/index.php`.

Upon contacting 1&1, they of course advised me to upgrade the package, well guess what 1&1, I have done it without paying more, and have a fully functional remote server for 99p a month. Quality.

Thanks anyway stackers!!!

Comment: Hi. It's 2018. I'm still facing this problem. All routes but / are returning a 404 when I upload to 1and1.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to fix this issue since long time and even the support team was not helpful to fix this issue. After trying many fixes I came to the conclusion that the hosting is not allowing to use the .htaccess properly inside the subfolder /public.

So I changed the path of domain to directly access the /public folder and then changed the .htaccess file **"RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]"** instead of "RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]" and now it is working perfectly.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```